# Cron job to connect to sql server and run a sproc using python

Tags: python

I want to learn python, and my task is the run a sql server 2008 stored procedure via a cron job.

Can someone step through a script for me in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you mean **Microsoft's** SQL server...

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import pymssql
con = pymssql.connect (host='xxxxx',user='xxxx',
                       password='xxxxx',database='xxxxx')
cur = con.cursor()
query = "DECLARE @id INT; EXECUTE sp_GetUserID; SELECT @id;"
cur.execute(query)
outputparameter = cur.fetchall()
con.commit()
con.close()
```

Taken from http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Python/comp.lang.python/2008-10/msg02620.html (copyright retained)

Put that in a script and run it from cron...

[Check this question too.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191644/how-do-you-get-output-parameters-from-a-stored-procedure-in-python)